# How to make a join table using EF core code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have these three models:

```
public class Card
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class Deck
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Class {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> DeckCards {get; set;}
}

public class DeckCard
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int DeckID {get; set;}
    public int CardID {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use the DeckCard model as a join table essentially.  I need to be able to populate it in my DecksController/Index view.  Can anyone give me guidance or point me in the right direction?

Note that the Card table is a static table (I don't know if that's the correct term for it but it will be populated and unchanged with whatever cards the game currently has (it's a deck building website)).

Comment: what specifically you want as the join result ? What did you try ?

Comment: I want the join result to be an entity of the DeckCard type.  Excuse me if that sounds stupid but I'm extremely new to this.

Comment: you want for a specific deck ?  (DeckId.. ???).

Comment: Yes.  For each deck in the database.  Users will be creating their own decks.

Comment: It will be essentially a list of cards in the Deck (for each existing deck).  The alternative is to create a nav property of Card types but after during production the card type will have too much information to duplicated every time it is used in the composition of a deck.  I'd rather just have a table of ID numbers.

Comment: [One way](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/)

Comment: if  you set models relation in model builder EF Automatic Create DeckCard Table

Comment: Do you want to do? if your answer is yes, I Send Full Answer for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First.** You Not need to Create model(DeckCard) for one to many relations so that EF Automatic Create This Table In Your Database.

**Second.** Add or override `OnModelCreating` Method in your DbContext Class For Example:

**MyApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
 public class MyApplicationDbContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
      
     public DbSet<Deck> Decks { get; set; }

     //This is the Model Builder
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     { 
           modelBuilder.Entity<Card>()
                .HasRequired<Card>(_ => _.Card)
                .WithMany(_ => _.Deck);
                
     }

 }
```

**DecksController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 { 
      var model = context.Card.AsNoTracking().Include(_ => _.Decks).ToList(); 
        
      return View(model);
 }
```

For a join query with **Eager loading** use `Include();`

also, see below Links:

[Getting more performance out of Entity Framework 6](http://dwyler.net/blog/getting-more-performance-out-of-entity-framework-6/)

[Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232)

[Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

[Relationships In EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: I'm using EF core, and I'm going to edit title to specify that, but '.HasRequired' isn't a method of any directive that I'm using.  Is there an equivalent for core?  Is this code establishing a one to many relationship, isn't that assumed by EF when you define a nav property (public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards {get; set;}  an entity of type Card with a property ID will automatically be mapped to the entity with the nav property definition... Right?

Comment: In the 1 to many relationship, the 1 is the Card and the many is the Deck right?  According to this code?

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw yes, think this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) Is Great For your Issue.

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw in this link that is Microsoft  doc Can Help you.

Comment: Should the relationship be many-to-many?  Each card will undoubtedly be used for more than one deck.

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw  yes, i think. These is your model. I Answer your main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132655/discussion-between-j3ssi3ftw-and-soheil-alizadeh).

Answer (score 2):

With your current entity structure, you can write a join between all three data sets and then do a group by on the DeckId and derive the results.

I would create 2 view model classes for this grouped data representation for my view.

```
public class DeckVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<CardVm> Cards { set; get; }
}
public class CardVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now the join

```
var decksWithCards = (from dc in db.DeckCards
                join d in db.Decks on dc.DeckID equals d.ID
                join c in db.Cards on dc.CardID equals c.ID
                select new { DeckId = d.ID, DeckName = d.Name,
                             CardId = c.ID, CardName = c.Name })
    .GroupBy(x => x.DeckId, d => d,
        (ky, v) =>
            new DeckVm
            {
                Id = ky,
                Name = v.FirstOrDefault().DeckName,
                Cards = v.Select(h => new CardVm { Id = h.CardId, Name=h.CardName})
            })
    .ToList();
```

`decksWithCards` will be a `List<DeckVm>` which you can pass to your view. You have to make your view strongly typed to `List<DeckVm>`