# EF Core saving a legacy join table record

Tags: .net-core, join, ef-core-2.2

I have a legacy join table that I am trying to insert a record into.  The 'RequistionId' comes from a newly created requisition and 'PanelId' is populated from a lookup table.

```
public class RequisitionPanel 
{         
    public int RequisitionId { get; set; }       
    public int PanelId { get; set; }
    public string PanelDescription { get; set; }
    ...

    public Requisition Requisition { get; set; }
    public Panel Panel { get; set; }     
}

public class Requisition 
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    ...

    public RequisitionPanel RequsitionPanel { get; set; }
}


public class Panel
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    ...

    public RequisitionPanel RequisitionPanel { get;set; }
}
```

DBContext

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }    

    public DbSet<Panel> Panels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Requisition> Requisitions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequisitionPanel> RequisitionPanels { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequisitionPanel>().HasKey(r => new { r.RequisitionId, r.PanelId });
        ...      
    }

}
```

How do I get the `RequistionPanel` to save automatically when I am saving a 'Requisition' and also insert the `PanelId` from the 'Panel' table?  More specifically how do I associate the `PanelId` to the context so it saves it in the `RequistionPanel` table in the `PanelId` field?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a join table using EF core code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535157/how-to-make-a-join-table-using-ef-core-code-first)

Comment: It doesn't because I have a legacy join table that I have to use unfortunately.  Also I'm trying to create the requisitionpanel record.

Comment: You will need to provide more info, wheres the code that saves the `Requisition`? [Provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)